# Google Adsense Api Access with API Key

Tags: php, adsense, google-api-php-client, adsense-api

I have wordpresss MU.

Every Author has his separate subdomain. But the whole website (main domain + all sub-domains) use a single AdSense account.

I am trying to make an earning report dashboard where the author enter the sub-domain name to get his earning report.

My question is: how to do the server side authentication of my google AdSense account.

Currently AdSense doesn't support Service account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Installed Application OAuth2 scenario to store refresh tokens and use them, basically, as you would use service account keys.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199357/3033153

Then, use the DOMAIN_NAME dimension to generate your reports.

Comment: Thank you very much . its worked . i wish i can vote up the answer .